# Move GRUB from USB to HD

Tags: debian, boot, grub, boot-loader

When I installed 
*Linux debian 2.6* and *GRUB* I managed to install it, the boot loader, on a usb flash drive. Right now, If the USB drive is plugged into the computer, the *GRUB* and the *OS* starts, otherwise, if the usb is out, nothing happens.

There are some grub files in `/boot/grub/` and `/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/` but there's no e.g. `menu.lst` in these directories, but a lot of other files.

To be honest, I don't know if I actually installed GRUB on the flash drive or not, but I can't start the OS without having the Flash drive inserted.

Well, what I would like to do is to be able to start the OS without having the USB plugged-in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While in the OS, try installing GRUB:

`grub-install /dev/sdX`
`update-grub`

Where /dev/sdX is the HDD where the bootloder should be installed.

This will move GRUB to your disk and set it up as to boot without the need of the LiveUSB.

Comment: GRUB must be instaled on a disk, not a partition. Try grub-install /dev/sda.