# Move /boot to usb Fedora

Tags: fedora, boot-loader

I'm a Linux Noob so bare with me.

Basically I am did a normal install to my ssd in my laptop.
Now I want to move the bootloader and kernel and every unencrypted file to a usb, so that it is only possible to boot with the usb plugged in.

Basically I am trying to do the opposite of this question:
[Move GRUB from USB to HD](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47105/move-grub-from-usb-to-hd)

I have looked around the Internet quite a bit, but couldn't find a step by step guide.
My long term goal is to install windows on the ssd as well, but make it only possible to boot Windows without the usb plugged in.

How can I set this up?

Thanks :)

Comment: That's quite an involved procedure. Is the Windows partition, which shouldn't be bootable (without the inserted USB drive) to be encrypted?

Comment: Just for clarification: the actual migration of bootloaders, etc. is the problem. If you were to install Windows to the hard disk anew, and disable the bootloader, and then set up the USB drive with the boot loader and and the Linux partition, it'd be much easier.

Comment: The migration of a Linux bootloader is essentially the same no matter what the destination device is. However, the procedure to migrate an UEFI-style bootloader is significantly different from migrating a legacy BIOS-style bootloader. Which one do you have? (If you run `efibootmgr -v` as root, what does it report?)

Comment: @polemon Thanks for looking into this! I think phrased my question not accurate enough. I want Windows to boot without the usb and have the Windows bootloader on the ssd. Linux on the other hand should only be booted with the usb plugged in. I also thought about just doing a reinstall and telling the installer to install /boot and /boot/efi to the usb.

Comment: @telcoM  Thanks for taking a look. It basically points to this .efi file ```/File(\EFI\fedora\shim.efi)```. Which then loads grub2, as fas as I know.

Comment: @jo_new ok, is the Linux system supposed to reside on the SSD next to the Windows partition, or is that also to be installed on the USB drive? As I understand it, you want both Windows and Linux next to each other on the SSD, however ONLY Grub is to be run from the USB stick, such that it'll load the Linux partition, is that correct?

Comment: @polemon Yes that is correct, the /(root) and /home partition reside encrypted on the ssd next to a complete windows install.

Comment: @jo_new please add that to your initial question. Edit it, such that all that we've gathered from comments is in your OP question.

Answer (score 1):

Since (according to the comments) you have an UEFI system, migrating just the bootloader might actually be rather simple.

Have the USB disk formatted as FAT32. If it's mounted as e.g. `/media/usbdisk`, create directory `/media/usbdisk/EFI`. Then copy the complete contents of `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora` directory into `/media/usbdisk/EFI`:

```
cp -r /boot/efi/EFI/fedora /media/usbdisk/EFI/
```

Make a second copy of the `fedora` directory as `boot`, and in it, rename `shim.efi` to `bootx64.efi`:

```
cd /media/usbdisk/EFI
cp -r fedora boot
cd boot
mv shim.efi bootx64.efi
```

Now your USB disk should be capable of booting the on-disk Linux installation!
At this point you can test it. If it works, you can change your `/etc/fstab` to mount the USB disk as `/boot/efi` instead of your existing EFI System Partition.

One possible problem remains, though: whenever you install a new kernel package, the package manager will update the bootloader configuration (on the USB disk) in `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg`, but the configuration file actually used at boot time will probably be `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/grub.cfg`. If it turns out you have this problem, you can replace `/boot/efi/EFI/boot/grub.cfg` with a "dummy" configuration file that has just one line:

```
configfile /EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

The resulting sequence of events at boot will then be:

1. firmware boots from USB in UEFI mode using the standard UEFI removable media/fallback boot path: `/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi` (relative to root of the USB disk filesystem)
2. `bootx64.efi` is actually `shim.efi` which handles Secure Boot issues and then starts `grubx64.efi` in the same directory
3. `grubx64.efi` reads the dummy `grub.cfg` in the same directory. The `configfile /EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` tells it to read the actual configuration file from the `/EFI/fedora` directory on the USB stick instead.
4. `grubx64.efi` reads the actual GRUB configuration file. Since a Secure Boot shim is in use, `grubx64.efi` must be a completely self-contained version, so any GRUB modules it needs will be built-in. So it can use exactly the same configuration as the SSD-installed version to load the kernel and initramfs files from wherever they are located on the SSD (encrypted or not).
5. `grubx64.efi` boots the Fedora kernel and initramfs, and the bootloader's job is done.
6. When Fedora starts up, it mounts the USB disk as `/boot/efi` according to `/etc/fstab`, so any future kernel updates will automatically update the `/boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg` on the USB disk.

If you have a separate `/boot` partition, and you specifically wish to move it onto the USB disk too, then you will need two partitions on the USB disk: one FAT32 partition (to be mounted as `/boot/efi`), and one Linux partition (to be mounted as `/boot`). In this case, the same GRUB configuration as in the SSD-boot case will no longer work; however, if you set up everything else before running `grub2-mkconfig`, it should still be able to create a suitable configuration file for you.

Answer (score -1):

in summary: you want to put the bootloader on a usb support to make it essential to start your linux system AND AT THE SAME TIME make it possible to start your windows system without the usb disk which contains the bootloader.
**It is NOT POSSIBLE to do this.**
Indeed, it is the bootloader which will load the GNU Linux system AND the MS Windows system.
If there is no bootloader, you will not boot the MS Windows OS

Comment: That's not true, the fallback Windows partition may contain its own bootloader. The USB-Drive can be the primary boot source with SYSLINUX or Grub2, which could chainload the Windows bootloader. Booting Windows since Windows XP is through chainloading the boot sector of the windows partitions. The newer versions of Windows even contain a separate boot partition. In fact that's how live-OSes usually boot. The Bootloader of Windows can be disabled, and/or the partition made unbootable.

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer Barikad. I am myself not very experienced with this stuff, but I know that the Windows Bootloader can reside on the ssd independent of the linux bootloader.

Comment: @polemon you're right, my bad